# MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging is a namespace but is used like a type

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I've just migrated to MvvmCross 4 and my app uses fragments.  The Setup class is as follows:

```
 public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    public Setup(Context applicationContext) : base(applicationContext)
    {
    }

    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()
    {
        return new AN.Core.App();
    }

    protected override IMvxTrace CreateDebugTrace()
    {
        return new DebugTrace();
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies => new List<Assembly>(base.AndroidViewAssemblies)
    {
        typeof(Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar).Assembly,
        typeof(Android.Support.V4.Widget.DrawerLayout).Assembly,
        typeof(Android.Support.V4.View.ViewPager).Assembly,
        typeof(MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging).Assembly,
    };

    protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
    {
        return new MvxFragmentsPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);
    }
```

What is the proper Assembly to reference in the last entry of AndroidViewAssemblies?  Is there a more optimal way of resolving the error received?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Build/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=FullFragging), it lists several references that are under the `MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging` namespace.

Your not specifying a `Type` to then get the `Assembly`.

As your only interested in the `.Assembly` you must specify one of the classes, for instance instead of:-

```
typeof(MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging).Assembly
```

try...

```
typeof(Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.FullFragging.MvxOwnedViewModelFragmentAttribute).Assembly
```

That will at least get around that 'namespace but is used like a type' error your experiencing.